# INSERTING and UPDATE SET issues when handling strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, python-3.5

I've been having this issue for some time now and here is the short story:

I want to edit a date in my `Sqlite` database with a `Python` script so I do this using:

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("UPDATE info SET date = '2003-03-14 12:34:20' WHERE id = 10")
```

but when I execute this I get an exception:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such module: fts4
```

with some troubleshooting I've managed to narrow it down to having some issues with the quote marks. Since even if I just reduce it to a single year it still produces an exception.

The same exception appear if I try to insert a string using quote marks.

How can I fix this? Most solutions I find is solved though enabling `fts3/fts4` with the `SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3` flag when building, but I have no idea of how to do that.

Besides, the exact same code runs smoothly both in `Python 3.6.5` and `2.7.12`. what happened in `Python3`?, or more specifically `3.5.2`.

I should add, that it works in linux but not in windows.

Comment: FTS3/FTS4 extensions are there to enable full text search so chances are that your `info` table is a virtual FTS table requiring the FTS4 engine to work while your Python's SQLite binary didn't include it. You cannot work-around it (apart from converting it to a _regular_ table) so you need to update your Python or at least its linked SQLite binary (e.g. when it comes to Windows, [download the precompiled SQLite binary](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) matching your version and replace the `sqlite3.dll` in your `%PYTHONHOME%\DLLs` folder with it).

Comment: it's working in 3.6.5 on windows. could I just copy the SQLite3 DLLs from 3.6.5 to 3.5.2?

Comment: Probably, provided both CPython versions are compiled for the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit / 64-bit).